# Tag wiki show a ... for the excerpt if it's too long

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I notice that if an excerpt is too long it cuts it shorter including in the middle of a word. I think it would be good if this happens that a ... with a link to the full wiki is placed at the end.

Comment: Link to an example would be nice. Or have you fixed it already?

Comment: I haven't seen it being cut in the middle of the word, but in the middle of the sentence. See e.g. [visual-c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b), [xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode), ...

Answer (score 3):

<strike>As Jon said, this is actually a bug. We should warn people before truncation and hard limit the length of tag wikis.</strike>

We will now display a warning and disallow the edit if you try to enter an excerpt that is longer than 460 chars. All excerpts must be shorter than that.

Comment: I think implementing a counter thingy like we already have on comments is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with this... except that the entire excerpt is already shown on the page.

There is a hard limit of 454 characters to the excerpt, with no warning if it's truncated, no character counter on the editing page, and the textbox where you type has no limit to it either.

The `[visual-c++]` excerpt is already at the max, while the `[xcode]` one is 452 characters long. The latter is because its excerpt was auto-generated by the system and I assume it seeked backwards from the limit to find the last word boundary.

It's also worth noting that newlines are kept in the revision data, but stripped on output.

---

I tested this by [modifying the `[feature-request]` excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63348/revisions) here on Meta.

Before I rolled back, [what gets shown on the page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) is this:

> You have an idea for a new feature to be added, or for a change in existing functionality. Great! Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature. See also: bug hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhh hhhhh